# Cocos2D v3.1 - Memory management issues with ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I've began using **Cocos2D v3.1** some days ago (was using v2 for my older projects), and there seems to be memory management issues when using **ARC**. When I profile my game, I see that my custom classes (subclassed from CCSprite) are released correctly; I have the exact same number of `#persistent` as the number of objects running in my scene. However, I saw that CCSpriteFrames number is constantly going up and never released. I looked around in the class `CCSprite`, and I found that there's no dealloc function (which can be logical because we are using ARC) but the `CCSpriteFrame` allocated for every sprite is never released, which means that I can stack up a good bunch of these objects, so my Memory usage keeps going up. Same thing for CCTexture when I am using particles.

So I was wondering if there's something I must do to dealloc those frames or if I am just not understanding something about ARC.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

P.S When my scene is replaced, `dealloc` is called in which I release all my objects by putting their references to `nil`, thus cascading through all my objects' dealloc method and releasing everything except CCSpriteFrame apparently.

Comment: Sprite frames and textures are automatically cached in private classes CCSpriteFrameCache and CCTextureCache.

Comment: I dont believe it is ARC related. First upgrade to 3.2.1, which fixed a few memory management issues for CCLableTTF and CCTextureCache.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But isn't there something I can do to clear this cache? Right now my game stack up a whole lot of sprites and I need the best memory usage possible

Comment: @YvesLeBorg What's the best way to install 3.2.1? Should I create a new project or replace the cocos2d's source files in my existing project with the new ones? I tried the second option and I am getting a lot of errors! :/

Comment: @UnluckyPotato yes, 3.2.1 will solve that for you, i prefer JIT texture loading and unload as fast as possible. I cant give you good advice if you are working with Xcode. With my tool, i prefer to start a new project from scratch and add-in my code and resources (10000 or so). It works well for this kind of use-case.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg how to install 3.2.1 templates to xcode? any tutorial or link ?

Comment: @Gururaj.T Unfortunately, as I was saying, i only use Xcode for very limited aspects in any project ... so I am not very current on its capabilities and 'features'.

Comment: Ok so I've tried all day long to migrate my project to 3.2.1, and there's a lot of problem going with it, so I've decided to keep 3.1 and to dig into cocos2d's libraries and found the method `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData]` which purge every texture and LabelBMF cached, but not SpriteFrames. Right now it's fair enough for me, but if anyone finds a way to purge the SpriteFrames it would be very useful! :)